# Differentiate FBA Users and domain users

Tags: forms-authentication, claims-based-auth

I have set-up FBA for my web-application. In Central Administration I have enabled both Windows NTLM Authentication and FBA to it.  I thought that

```
SPClaimProviderManager.IsEncodedClaim(SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName)
```

will give be True for FBA users and False for AD users. However, it is returning True for both type of users. Also,
`SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName` is returning `"i:0#.w|domain\internalusername”` for internal user and   `“i:0#.f|fba_membershipprovider|fbausername”` for fba users. Why is it so?
How do I differentiate them in my code using `SPClaimProviderManager`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is here:

All Windows Claims contain a 'w':

```
i:0#.w
```

And all Forms Claims contain an 'f':

```
i:0#.f
```

This would be the best way, in a generic sense, to determine if the user is a Domain or Forms-based user.

This [TechNet Wiki](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13921.sharepoint-20102013-claims-encoding.aspx) article goes into detail about what the various letters and symbols mean.

Comment: That's definetely the good and only answer I know of!